# How to find all the unique substrings of a very long string?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, memory, large-data

I have a very long string. I want to find all the unique substrings of this string. I tried to write the code where I used a *set*(python) to store all the substrings to ensure uniqueness. I am getting correct result for many medium and large strings however in case of very large strings, I am getting a MemoryError. I googled a bit and found out that the *set* data structure in python has a large RAM footprint and maybe thats why I am getting a MemoryError.

Here is my code :

```
a = set()
for i in range(n):
    string = raw_input()
    j = 1
    while True:
        for i in xrange(len(string)-j+1):   
            a.add(string[i:i+j])
        if j==len(string):   break
        j+=1
print sorted(list(a))
```

Is there a way to avoid this error for large strings? Or can anybody suggest a better modification in my code to handle this issue?

P.S: I donot have an option of shifting between 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

Comment: There are about n² substrings, so unless your string has a great amount of redundancy, any explicit enumeration (even if only giving start and end indices) of unique substrings will necessarily take a boatload of memory. There *might* be a more compressed representation (cf. suffix trees storing all suffixes in linear memory), but I see little hope.

Comment: @delnan: My point is that I can manage strings of length quite more than what I can now if somehow I can do this without 'set'. SET really takes a lot of RAM, much much more than a simple list in python. I am just trying to find a way to do this without using set, if possible.

Comment: How big are is "very long"?  Also, how much duplication do you expect?  If you expect most of the longer strings to be unique, then I suspect the best way is to simply enumerate all the strings in a list, sort the list, and then filter duplicates.  If the list of substrings won't fit in memory as a list, write it out to disk and use a sorting algorithm that works on disk like merge sort.

Comment: Well, you can certainly reduce memory requirements *somewhat*. You could maintain a set of "slices" (objects referring to part of an original string without actually constructing that substring). Since you have obly a single superstring, it's enough to store `(i, i+j)` instead of `string[i:i+j]`. *If*, after doing that, you find yourself *almost but not quite* in reach of the target (e.g. out of memory after 90% of the results being generated), you might also look into sets specialized for storing compact data like pairs of integer and perhaps implemented in C.

Comment: What are you doing with the substrings afterwards?

Comment: @Evan: Very big in my case are strings with length > 1961 characters. But the strings contain only lowercase alphabets, so you can expect moderate duplication. I can only think of using a dictionary instead of a set to save some memory.I was wondering if there was a better way to do this in RAM itself

Comment: In python AFAIK sets are implemented with the same hash table implementation as dictionaries, just with empty values.  So you won't save anything that way.  The efficient structure for this is some sort of tree which holds the substrings in sorted order and allows efficient insertion.  Unfortunately python doesn't have such a thing built in, which means it will be slow and huge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need it in memory, then you can try making a suffix tree.  Tries are not exotic data structures, so there are probably good implementations available for a mainstream language like Python, and they can be used to implement suffix trees.  [Marisa-Trie](https://github.com/kmike/marisa-trie) is supposed to get good memory usage.

1. Create an empty trie.
2. For each n in [0, len(s)], add the suffix of length n to the Trie.
3. Every path from the root of the trie is a substring in the string, there are no such paths that are not substrings in the string, and paths are unique.

Comment: This creates a trie of all suffixes (a poor man's suffix tree). OP wants all substrings. Of course, this only requires a minor modification to your instructions. Still, a memory efficient trie is somewhat complicated to construct (doubly so in Python where everything's a reference type and even simple objects take 28 bytes or more).

Comment: @delnan, Every substring is a prefix of a suffix :)  Note that I didn't say "to a leaf" when I talked about "path from the root".

Comment: And there we have the compressed storage structure I've been looking for! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Python code based on a O(n) suffix tree construction to produced the unique  substrings from a collection of input strings (the output should appear in sorted order so there is no need to sort the strings afterwards).

As there can be O(n^2) output strings it may take a long time to actually output all the strings.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class SuffixTree:
    def __init__(self):
        """Returns an empty suffix tree"""
        self.T=''
        self.E={}
        self.nodes=[-1]

    def add(self,s):
        """Adds the input string to the suffix tree.

        This inserts all substrings into the tree.
        End the string with a unique character if you want a leaf-node for every suffix.

        Produces an edge graph keyed by (node,character) that gives (first,last,end)
        This means that the edge has characters from T[first:last+1] and goes to node end."""
        origin,first,last = 0,len(self.T),len(self.T)-1
        self.T+=s
        nc = len(self.nodes)
        self.nodes += [-1]*(2*len(s))
        T=self.T
        E=self.E
        nodes=self.nodes

        Lm1=len(T)-1
        for last_char_index in xrange(first,len(T)):
            c=T[last_char_index]
            last_parent_node = -1                    
            while 1:
                parent_node = origin
                if first>last:
                    if (origin,c) in E:
                        break             
                else:
                    key = origin,T[first]
                    edge_first, edge_last, edge_end = E[key]
                    span = last - first
                    A = edge_first+span
                    m = T[A+1]
                    if m==c:
                        break
                    E[key] = (edge_first, A, nc)
                    nodes[nc] = origin
                    E[nc,m] = (A+1,edge_last,edge_end)
                    parent_node = nc
                    nc+=1  
                E[parent_node,c] = (last_char_index, Lm1, nc)
                nc+=1  
                if last_parent_node>0:
                    nodes[last_parent_node] = parent_node
                last_parent_node = parent_node
                if origin==0:
                    first+=1
                else:
                    origin = nodes[origin]

                if first <= last:
                    edge_first,edge_last,edge_end=E[origin,T[first]]
                    span = edge_last-edge_first
                    while span <= last - first:
                        first+=span+1
                        origin = edge_end
                        if first <= last:
                            edge_first,edge_last,edge_end = E[origin,T[first]]
                            span = edge_last - edge_first

            if last_parent_node>0:
                nodes[last_parent_node] = parent_node
            last+=1
            if first <= last:
                    edge_first,edge_last,edge_end=E[origin,T[first]]
                    span = edge_last-edge_first
                    while span <= last - first:
                        first+=span+1
                        origin = edge_end
                        if first <= last:
                            edge_first,edge_last,edge_end = E[origin,T[first]]
                            span = edge_last - edge_first
        return self

    def make_choices(self):
        """Construct a sorted list for each node of the possible continuing characters"""
        choices = self.choices = [list() for n in xrange(len(self.nodes))] # Contains set of choices for each node
        for (origin,c),edge in self.E.items():
            choices[origin].append(c)
        choices=[sorted(s) for s in choices] # should not have any repeats by construction
        return choices

    def find_substrings(self,A,term):
        """Recurses through the tree appending unique substrings into A.
        Strings assumed to use term as the terminating character"""
        choices = self.make_choices()
        def f(node,depth):
            t=0
            for c in choices[node]:
                if c==term: continue
                first,last,end = self.E[node,c]
                # All end points along this edge result in new unique substrings
                edge_len = last-first+1
                a = first-depth
                for b in range(first,last+1):
                    if self.T[b]!=term:
                        A.append( self.T[a:b+1] )
                f(end,depth+edge_len)
            return t
        return f(0,0)

def fast_find_all_substrings(strings):
    S = SuffixTree()
    term = '\0'
    for string in strings:
        S.add(string+term)
    A=[]
    S.find_substrings(A,term)
    return A

A="abc","abcd","bca"
print fast_find_all_substrings(A)
```