# Optimal way of lexically arranging all substrings of a string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, sorting

I have been trying to solve this problem which states that:

```
Given a string S , generate a string Y such that:

Y = concatenate( lexically_sorted ( list_of_all_distinct_substrings_of_S ) ) 

1<=length_of_S <= 10^5
```

Mysolution is correct on small cases such as:

```
S = dbac
```

But my code is failing on larger strings with segmentation fault:

```
S = judaioobpoiteiszvzlscmpmpqqwuvtdqzdapudfimaowsnttalwndievaapwusmtyoksrpcfpqbkgvfiibvlkbjkcy
```

Input format:

```
T #no of testcases
S #given string S
```

Output Format:

```
Y #resultant string Y
```

MySolution Python code:

```
import sys
import itertools

def lex_arrange_substring(s):
    com=[list(itertools.combinations(s,x)) for x in range(1,len(s)+1)]
    substring_list = list(set([''.join(e) for e in sum(com,[])]))
    substring_list = sorted(substring_list)
    final_string = ''
    for x in substring_list:
        final_string = final_string + x
    return final_string

#for reading standard input
inp = sys.stdin.readlines()
t = str(inp[0]).rstrip('\n')
t = int(t)
i = 1    
while i < len(inp):
    s = str(inp[i]).rstrip('\n')
    fstring = lex_arrange_substring(s)
    print fstring
    i = i+1
```

Can anyone help me out in understanding the problem or by providing a better alternative solution. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I would not interpret "substrings" as being `combinations`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right. I am learning python but I am not sure of how to exactly get the list of distinct substrings optimally. Further, I think there must be some hack for such problems where there is no need to generate and store all substrings. But unfortunately, the optimal logic is not striking me at all. I am still thinking. Thanks!

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23766570/3001761

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. This link contains the recipe for such problems.