# Finding all the unique substrings of a long Python string- performance

Tags: python, arrays, string

I thought I had a very simple problem at hand- find all the substrings of a given string.

I did it as follows:

`unique_substrings = list(set([p[i:j+1+i] for i in range(len(p)) for j in range(len(p))]))`

But the performance is very poor. On a randomly generated string of length 900, it takes me 1.5 secs. Then I do a length based mathematical operation on each substring, which further costs more time, adding 3-4 secs.

How can I improve the performance in terms of time?

There is already a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766570/how-to-find-all-the-unique-substrings-of-a-very-long-string), but it pertains to memory. Memory is not my bottleneck.

Comment: Whatever you do, you will have an effort of O(n²) for time and memory if you consider all substrings.  Maybe, depending on your usecase, you can improve your surrounding program (the one needing all the substrings) by _generating_ all the substrings from shortest to longest.  Here I assume that you might want to abort the generation when you found something which matches something else, so that generating the longer ones isn't necessary anymore.  This might also drastically reduce your memory footprint.  Maybe you'd like to share what you need this for so we can work on this, too.

Comment: Using huge amounts of memory always is also a time performance issue because this memory needs to be allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can halve the number of loop iterations if you think about where your start and points currently are.  At the moment, `i + j` often exceeds the length of the string.

Instead try:

```
substrings = {p[i:j] for i in range(len(p)) for j in range(i + 1, len(p) + 1)}
```

Here we alter the semantics to make `i` the start point and `j` the end point, enforcing that `j > i`.

This will *not* include the empty string `""`.  Add it with `substrings.add("")` if appropriate.

Comment: A set comprehension `{...}` is slightly faster than wrapping a list comprehension `set([...])`. It's also shorter.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but there's another difference in behaviour that might need noting: OP's version includes the empty string, this does not.